# How to use IDC to clear output window in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida

As a beginner I'm trying to use IDC to clear output window in IDA Pro,but I don't know which function will work.

My IDA Pro version is 6.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easy

```
form = idaapi.find_tform("Output window")
idaapi.switchto_tform(form, True);
idaapi.process_ui_action("msglist:Clear");
```

Comment: The names have changed, see [this answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/30375/245)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is one, so I tend to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> in the console window, which is the same as right-clicking and picking <kbd>Clear</kbd> from the context menu, before running my IDC scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
form = idaapi.find_widget("Output window")
idaapi.activate_widget(form, True)
idaapi.process_ui_action("msglist:Clear")
print('---------------IDA Python Running at {}---------------------'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
```